# How is anyone processing payments with React Native apps at present?

Tags: react-native, paypal, stripe-payments

Trust me when I say I've tried every single solution people are currently downloading. tipsi-stripe, react-native-payments, react-native-paypal, you name it.

Every single guide says to link the library using link. Or automatically using yarn/npm. I've tried both ways, doesn't work. The new React Native version is certainly preventing this, and all the npm packages are failing. It seems no one can update the packages to work with react native yet.

If this is the case, how is anyone at all processing payments in react native? There doesn't appear to be any workable option here. Going to have to cancel my client's project due to impossible needs, simply payments.

Comment: What kind of payments are you processing? IAP or payment gateways (like Stripe)? We are currently using `tipis-stripe` on 0.63.3 and although there are some deprecations from the package everything is working fine. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried tipsi-stripe more than any other method. payment gateways, okay with Stripe or paypal. Every guide I've followed doesn't link tipsi stripe properly. This includes using 'react-native link,' adding Stripe to podfile, adding tipsi-stripe path to podfile, pod install, (not using expo), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the best solution is to have a server or webservice that calls an API like PayPal v2/checkout/orders, to set up and capture a transaction. See "Create Order" and "Capture Order" here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls

Then, for the approval flow, you can open a [secure browser view](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications) to the approval_url the create call returns, having set the return_url in your creation to be a deeplink back to your app, which when opened immediately calls your server or webservice to do the capture and respond with success/failure.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for this. I have been considering using an API on the back end in a server using Firebase like Firebase functions, then I could just send the user input card info to the back end. I will check out the PayPal API solution although I ideally liked Stripe. I will give these links a try, thanks again for your help!